# How do I convert a plain HTML-code into a value of react-quill text editor?

Tags: reactjs, text-editor, rich-text-editor, react-quill

I'm using `react-quill` as a rich-text editor. I need to insert an already existing HTML code so it will be displayed as a text inside of the editor. Is there any ability to do something like this?

```
let htmlSample = "<p>It's a test html <b>to be inserted!</b></p>
<ReactQuill htmlValue="{htmlSample}" />
```

And the results would look like:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I got this. If anyone else wonders how to insert plain html - simply put your custom editor area like this:

```
<ReactQuill value={this.state.value}>
<div class="your-custom-container">
<p>your custom html</p>
</div>
</ReactQuill>
```